# In Android, how I implement a global touch track service which works even if other applications are running on the screen

Tags: java, android, service, touch

I am working on developing an Android application that works as a background service and aims to record all touch events' coordinates. I tried several solutions and suggestions, but they did not work as I aimed. I defined a GlobalTouchService extends Service implements View.OntouchListener. It works when the application works on the foreground, but I want to detect touch events when other applications work in the foreground. This solution return always zeroes as coordinates of touch when other applications work in the foreground.

This is my MainActivity:

```
package com.token.simpledatabaseproject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.icu.text.AlphabeticIndex;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class GlobalTouchService extends Service implements View.OnTouchListener {

WindowManager.LayoutParams params;

private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
private WindowManager mWindowManager;
private LinearLayout touchLayout;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    touchLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    touchLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);       
    touchLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);


    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(touchLayout, params);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mWindowManager != null) {
        if (touchLayout != null) mWindowManager.removeView(touchLayout);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("Touchhhhhhhhhhhhhh: ", String.valueOf(event.getX()) + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
    return true;
 }
}
```

This is my GlobalTouchService:

```
package com.token.simpledatabaseproject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class GlobalTouchService extends Service implements View.OnTouchListener {

WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
private WindowManager mWindowManager;
private LinearLayout touchLayout;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // create linear layout
    touchLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    // set layout width 30 px and height is equal to full screen
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    touchLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
    // set color if you want layout visible on screen
    touchLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    // set on touch listener
    touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);

    // fetch window manager object
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);


    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(touchLayout, params);

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mWindowManager != null) {
        if (touchLayout != null) mWindowManager.removeView(touchLayout);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    Log.d("Touchhhhhhhhhhhhhh: ", String.valueOf(event.getX()) + String.valueOf(event.getY()));      
    return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: "I am working on developing an Android application that works as a background service and aims to record all touch events' coordinates" -- this is not possible, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: This application would not work on a cell phone, I will use for another Android device. I would have root permission or other required permissions. Is it still impossible?

Comment: On a rooted device, there should be options (custom firmware, Xposed module, etc.). However, the implementation is not going to resemble the code in your question.

Comment: Did you find a solution for rooted device?

Comment: I tried a way that create a window like as facebook chathead. I succeed keep on top this small (It could be 1 pixel) window. However, when you touch the outside the this small window, android return 0,0 in my case. I read about this problem, someone wrote because of android security policy, but I suggest to try for your case. It could be dependent to Android version.